# Change standard authorization in VF04

Tags: authorization, abap, sap-erp

I need to change the authorization for billing type in transaction VF04, to be editable for all users.

Is there some user exit for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The authorization object for billing types is `V_VBRK_FKA`, and its check is located in program `SAPLV05H` include `LV05HFBE`, and technically you can make a modification (strongly discouraged!) to remove this check but why? It is is weird to try to suppress standard checks.

Why not to add this type to authorization profiles of all users in order this check to be passed? If you want to allow certain billing type for all users, **just create the role and assign it to all users.**